# Robolectric IllegalState Exception

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, robolectric

I'm running into a strange IllegalStateException and I think it is a problem with Robolectric. This is the stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:340)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:309)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:273)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:136)
at com.sr.dd.dd_app.screens.main.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:87)
```

MainActivity.java line 87

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

activity_main.xml:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <ListView android:id="@+id/main_left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left|start"
        android:background="#FFFFFF" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>`

The Unit Test where the Activity is instantiated:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, shadows = {ShadowGoogleApiAvailability.class}, manifest="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml")
public class ScreenUnitTest {
    ... //Some unimportant stuff
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        ... //More unimportant stuff
        mainActivity = Robolectric.setupActivity(MainActivity.class);
    }
}
```

build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.+'
    androidTestCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker:1.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.3.0'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.+'
    testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.1'
    testCompile "org.robolectric:shadows-support-v4:3.1"
    testCompile "org.robolectric:shadows-play-services:3.1"
    testCompile 'org.robolectric:shadows-maps:3.1'
    testCompile 'org.khronos:opengl-api:gl1.1-android-2.1_r1'
    testCompile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'

    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.+'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.4'
}
```

Compiling with Sdk version 23

Just wondering if anyone else has seen this. It looks similar to other questions, but the answers I have found aren't helping.

Comment: Use Activity instead of AppCompatActivity

Comment: @MarkShen I'm trying to use DrawerLayout which is only in support-v4.

Comment: @MarkShen I changed all my Fragments to non support fragments, and I changed my Activities to non support Activities. I now get a IllegalStateException: Recursive entry to executePendingTransactions. :/

Answer (score 1):

Remove the manifest entry from your config tag, robolectric will find it self. Or when necessary then use the manifest file located in your build directory. This is a common mistake and then robolectric can't find some stuff.

Comment: That didn't do anything. I changed all my Fragments to non support fragments, and I changed my Activities to non support Activities. I now get a IllegalStateException: Recursive entry to executePendingTransactions.

Comment: The support library exists not only for compatibility, but also for new API that is not available in SDK

Comment: For the recursive call issue we need to see your code. Such error is common when you have add and replace fragment logic.